# Get HashMap in Spring Controller

Tags: spring, rest, controller, hashmap

Actually I am trying to make an android application for my office canteen for that a Spring web application is already there. In Android app I am showing all the items available for that particular day. Employee will fill qty to the respective item and just submit. For that I have created a webService in Spring controller and I am able to access all the items in android app through REST (using `getForObject`). I have given id's to EditText as item_id(taken from remote database using rest) and whenever user click on place order, I create one HashMap in that I put item_id, order qty for all the items. But I am facing problem to send that HashMap to Spring web application using rest. I tried to send Using `restTemplate.getForObject("http://172.16.1.2/webapp/rest/restPlaceOrder?order="+order, List.class);` . But it was receiving  in the form of  .../restPlaceOrder?order={1=2,2=7,8=4}. As you said I supposed to use postForObject instead of getForObject. Now i tried to use postForObject and also using @RequestBody in spring controller. But now whenever I use @RequestBody in spring controller, android restclient gives error that **unsupported media type**. So please help me in sending HashMap using postForObject and catch the same thing in spring controller. I am using code in android client as

```
 HashMap<Integer, Integer> order=new HashMap<Integer, Integer>(); 
order.put(1, 5); order.put(2, 4);
String url="http://172.16.1.2/webapp/rest/restPlaceOrder"
RestTemplate restTemplate1=new RestTemplate();
restTemplate1.getMessageConverters().add(new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter());
List<LinkedHashMap> res=restTemplate1.postForObject(url, null, List.class, order);
```

and at web application in Spring Controller, I am using

```
@RequestMapping(value="/restPlaceOrder", method= {RequestMethod.GET, RequestMethod.POST}, headers="Accept=application/json")
    public @ResponseBody List<Schedule> placeOrder(@RequestBody HashMap<Integer, Integer> order, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Model m){
         System.out.println("welcome taking request");
         /*problem is whenever i put @RequestBody, Restclient shows unsupported media type and if I remove @RequestBody, then it works but then how to get that HashMap here */  
        List<Schedule> sc=new ArrayList();
        return sc;

          }
```

Comment: Do you really want your URL to look like `.../restPlaceOrder?order={1=2,2=7,8=4}`? You shouldn't rely on HashMap's toString() to design your URLs. What is this map supposed to be? Your method is named `placeOrder()`. I thus assume it's meant to **create** something, not get something. So it should use a POST, not a GET.

Comment: Yeah JB, absolutely correct. what i want to do with this order map(Integer, Integer) is to store the pair of (item_id, qty) to the database but i dont know how to get this map from rest webservice call to spring contrloler.

Comment: As I said: use a POST rather than a GET, send that Map as the body of the request rather than as a query parameter, and get it on the server by annotating the parameter with `@RequestBody` rather than `@RequestParam`. And since you're expecting a Map<Integer, Integer>, make that the type of the method parameter rather thah Object.

Comment: But whenever I put HashMap in request body like postForObject(url, null, String.class, order) and use @RequestBody HashMap<Integer, Integer> or it shows unsupproted media type error in android client

Comment: Elaborate that problem in your question. Tell what you're doing, post the code, post the complete stack trace of the exception. What does android have to do with this? You have a Spring server, and a Spring client.

Comment: I was putting wrong parameters in `postForObject`. Now it is working. Thanks for your reply and suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Use @RequestParam

```
@RequestMapping(value="/restPlaceOrder", method= {RequestMethod.POST})
public @ResponseBody List<Schedule> placeOrder(@RequestParam HashMap<Integer, Integer> order, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Model m){
     System.out.println("welcome taking request");

    List<Schedule> sc=new ArrayList();
    return sc;

      }
```